# cur php to login to a site but is not working

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying to login to this site via curl but is not working i am always redirected to the same page.Why?

I used cookie jar to save the result but i have the same problem.maibe it is about referrer header and the server don't accepr curl requests and if i cant use curl what i am supposed to use?

```
<code>
    // Initialize cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://numbering.neustar.biz/secure');
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36";
    // Enable HTTP POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    // Set POST parameters
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
                                  'Login' => 'lnp@sixtel.net',
                                  'Password' => 'Temp12345',
                                  'RedirectURI' => 'secure',
                                  'submitted' => 'submitted'
                                  ));

    // Imitate classic browser's behavior - handle cookies
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiepula.txt');
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookiepula.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://numbering.neustar.biz/secure"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


    // Execute 1st request
    $store = curl_exec($ch);    

    curl_close($ch);

    $fisier=fopen("fisier.txt", "w+");
    fwrite($fisier, $store);
    fclose($fisier);
    echo $store;
</code>
```